# no lock and the usage of table name in from clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a question regarding the following query (an excerpt taken from complete query):

```
SELECT 
    'progress' as Status,
     sum(ProgressCount) as Count
     From  mydatabase..my_datasummary (nolock)
```

1)Regarding the 'progress' as Status in the above query, what is it supposed to do?
I haven't seen such thing before. The field is not in the database either.

2) My database structure is as follows:

Database Name : mydatabase

One of the relavent table name among the various other in the "mydatabse" database is

pqr.my_datasummary. However, in the above query, there are two dots used. Someone told
me that it has something to do with the current user or something else. I am not sure.
Could anyone please clarify?

3) As far as "nolock" is concerned, could you briefly tell me what it is used for?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'progress' as Status
```

This selects a constant string, which will be repeated verbatim for every row found in the table.

```
FROM mydatabase..my_datasummary
```

This isn't legal MySQL syntax. In Microsoft SQL Server, it means the `mydatabase` is a database name, and `my_datasummary` is a table, and there's an implicit owner name, which defaults to `dbo`. These concepts of data organization aren't supported in MySQL.

```
(nolock)
```

This syntax is also specific to Microsoft SQL Server, it's a [table hint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx). It doesn't mean anything in MySQL, and will result in a syntax error.

Are you sure you tagged your question appropriately?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tagged SQL-Server and removed mysql.